# How to disable real-time bindings in AngularFire2

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, angularfire2

Some part of my application needs to have the option to **load more updates** when data has been added to the database. However, I cannot find any documentation in AngularFire2 that states how to **disable real-time binding** of objects/lists. When I add data to the Firebase console, it **automatically updates** my application's view. I need to catch the event (after adding data) first, then show an option that allows users to load more updates.

home.ts

```
// Import AF2
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import {AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
    posts: FirebaseListObservable<any>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, af: AngularFire) {
    this.posts = af.database.list('/posts');
  }
}
```

home.html

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let post of posts | async">
      {{post.about}}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Note: I'm using **Ionic 2**.

Comment: "I need to catch the event (after adding data) first, then show an option that allows users to load more updates." I recommend reconsidering this requirement. A large part of the point of the Firebase Database is that your users *don't* have to initiate the updates manually anymore.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Good point. However, it's difficult to reconsider the requirement because users could be annoyed if posts are always adding up and pushing down other posts, which they could be looking into. Do you mind throwing some suggestion/s?

Comment: How you display things should be separate from the data flow. If you look at how sites like twitter and Facebook handle this, they don't auto-scroll to new items, but do auto-alert the user when there's new content.

Comment: Okay I'll try it to be like that. Thanks a lot.